# how to add fields to database and connect to code

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans

I'm trying to make a program using netbeans..

```
login_form.java

-2 labels : username & password

-1 textfield : username

-1 password field : password

-3 buttons : login , cancel , register

database named : try

-table named account

table account

-2 columns : username & password

registration_form.java

-2 labels : desired username & desired password

-1 textfield : username

-1 passwordfield : password

-2 buttons : register & back to login
```

what code should i put to connect and add fields in the registration_form to the database and be retrieved in login_form??

i have this code

```
public void addUser(LoginHandler account)
{
    String query = null;
    try
    {
        query = "INSERT INTO users(Username,Password)VALUES('"+account.getUsername()+"','"+account.getPassword()+"')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Register Success!",null,JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Register Failed!" + e.toString(),null,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

where am i going to call this? and how?

our teacher just gave this code to us..

SOMEONE HELP PLEASE???

Comment: First thing you need to do is to create UI for the elements you mentioned and then proceed to the work you wanted to do after your button is pressed.

Comment: already done that.. but where to call this method??

Comment: when your button is pressed just call that method get values of those elements and insert them

Comment: also make database connection which you haven't made

Comment: i already done saving it to database.. my problem now is how can i retrieve the fields saved in my database..  so that i can log in to my system now..

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is to retrieve that data, from the data base and get that in a resultset and save them in variables,for that you can use select query and modify accordingly.

```
ResultSet rs = (data you get from you query)
```

itrate the resultset for each of you row. 
and match it from the user information you get to login if matches then do you task else show error accordingly.for example you can view

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/navigate-result-sets.htm[example][1]